# ArrayFormula to find the last matching value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas

I am using below formula to find the last matching value
but how can i expand it with ArrayFormula
=index(filter(A:A,B:B=F3),SUMPRODUCT(B:B=F3))

I expect to have a arrayformula to work with index and filter but couldnt

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP(F3:F, B:B, A:A,,,-1))
```

or:

```
=BYROW(F3:F, LAMBDA(f, INDEX(FILTER(A:A, B:B=f), SUMPRODUCT(B:B=f))))
```

Comment: I Feel LAMBDA is bit slow to formulate.
any other variant that could work...

xlookup is fantastic but the issue of importrange is a problem

Comment: Also can this 2 formulas can be merged
=BYROW(F3:F, LAMBDA(x, INDEX(FILTER(A:A, B:B=x), SUMPRODUCT(B:B=x)))
)   **&**    =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((G3:G>0)*ISNUMBER(G3:G),(today()-K3:K)-((EOMONTH(K3:K, 0)-K3:K)+10), G3:G))  **K3 is were the LAMBDA formula is**

Comment: @SkilzWork you can try something like: `=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, XLOOKUP(F3:F, INDEX(x,,2), INDEX(x,,1),,,-1))
 (IMPORTRANGE("url_or_id", "sheetname!A:B")))`

Answer (score 0):

Try with BYROW:

```
=BYROW(F3:F,LAMBDA(each(if(each="","",index(filter(A:A,B:B=each),SUMPRODUCT(B:B=eacg)))))
```

You could also use XLOOKUP (-1 in search mode) with ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA (XLOOKUP(F3:F,B:B,A:A,"",0,-1))
```

Comment: I have tried xlookup but it creates a weird importrange issue.