# Google Sheets Arrayformula to find prior values based on prior value matches from same column?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Would like to match a prior answer in the same column with an arrayformula. For example, if in row 4: A4="" B4=sam then lookup sam in B2:B3 and return any matches in A2:A3 and do the same for others, I see why this might be a circular reference.

TEST SHEET

```
A2:A
red
blue
(no value)

B2:B
sam
Tabatha
sam

Formula in C1
no value
no value
red
```

Tried `XLOOKUP(C76, C1:C75, A1:75, "", 0, 1)` which causes sheets to flash between the value and an error

Similar to `=INDEX(XLOOKUP(F3:F, B:B, A:A,,,-1))` or `=BYROW(F3:F, LAMBDA(f, INDEX(FILTER(A:A, B:B=f), SUMPRODUCT(B:B=f))))` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565229/arrayformula-to-find-the-last-matching-value)

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with a bit more *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.